# Prove that the star of a point is an open subset of underlying space of a simplicial complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

From Rotman's **Algebraic Topology**

> Prove that $\text{st} (p)$ is an open subset of $|K|$, where $|K|$ is the underlying space of a simplicial complex and $\text{st} (p)$ is defined as $\bigcup_{s \in K, p \in \text{Vert}(s)} s^{\circ}$.

I can see that $\text{st}(p)$ is open iff $|K| - \text{st}(p)$ is closed in $|K|$, which is true iff $s' \cap (|K| - \text{st}(p))$ is closed for each $s' \in K$.

If $s'$ doesn't contain the vertex $p$, then then $s' \cap (|K| - \text{st}(p)) = s'$, which is closed in $s'$.

But if $s'$ contains the vertex $p$, then $s' \cap (|K| - \text{st}(p)) = s' - s' \cap \text{st}(p)$ is closed is what needs to be shown.

Either that or $s' \cap \text{st}(p)$ must be shown to be open.  I can see this is true in visualizable space, but I'm not sure how to show this for any arbitrary simplex of higher dimensions.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Let $x=\sum_{i=0}^kt_iv_i\in\text{St}(p)$, then $x$ belongs to exactly one simplex whose vertices are $p=v_0,v_1,...,v_k$. By definition, we require $\forall t_i>0$ for $x$ to be located in the interior, which implies that $\text{St}(x)$ is open. Does this help?

Comment: Munkres = Munkres J. R.: *Elementary Differential Topology*, 2nd ed., Princeton: Princeton University Press, 1968.<br/>
Dugundji = Dugundji, J.: *Topology*, Boston: Allyn and Bacon, 1966.<br/> The openness of $\text{St }(x,K)$ [Munkres, p.70, l.11--l.12] follows from [Dugundji, p.172, l.$-$15]. This is the only place where I have found the most direct and effective definition and proof for the star of a vertex. For details, see Example 6.162 in http://www.lcwangpress.com/papers/methods.pdf and the first four lines of §35.II in http://www.lcwangpress.com/papers/proofs.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p\in s'$. Then $p$ has vertices $p_0=p,p_1,\ldots,p_d$. Then $s'\cap(|K|-\mathrm{st}(p))$ is then the $(d-1)$-simplex spanned by $p_1,\ldots,p_d$.
It's a facet of $s'$ and so a closed subset of $s'$.

Comment: Can you show why $s' \cap (| K| - \text{st}(p))$ is a $(d-1)$-simplex spanned by $p_1, \dots, p_d$?  I can't figure out how to prove this.

Comment: Because the simplices in the star of $p$ are precisely those which contain $p$.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  I don't understand how that shows that the intersection is a $(d-1)$-simplex.

Comment: I cannot see how I can be more plain than this. Consider the simplex with vertices $p,p_1,\ldots,p_d$. The faces of this simplex which don't contain $p$ correspond to the non-empty subsets of $\{p_1,\ldots,p_d\}$.

Comment: $p \in S $ implies $s^o$ is included in $st(p)$ hence its not in the above intersection. What is left is the boundary of the simplex $s'$, but any of the proper faces of $[p,p_1,...,p_d]$ which include $p$ gives us a simplex that its open simplex will be in $st(p)$. So, only the $[p_1,...,p_d]$ remains.